# Is it possible to pass a string of column names to tidy-select?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to make a function where tidy-select is going to be called (as part of pivot_longer), and I wanted to be able to pass a string of column names to the function so that it isn't hard-coded.

For example

```
column<- c("c1","c2")
df %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = column,...)
```

As far as I can tell, you can't do this because tidy-select will only take the names directly

For example

```
pivot_longer(df, cols = c(c1,c2),...)
```

Any tips on what I want to do?

Comment: You could simply use `df %>%  pivot_longer(cols = column)` and it wlll also work with a warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `all_of`:

```
pivot_longer(df, cols = all_of(column),...)
```

From the `tidyr` manual:

> If you have a character vector of column names, use *all_of()* or
> *any_of()*, depending on whether or not you want unknown variable names
> to cause an error, e.g *unnest(df, all_of(vars))*, *unnest(df,
> -any_of(vars))*.

Comment: Do you know how to do the same thing for group_by?

I tried doing 

```{r}
df %>%
    group_by(all_of(grouping))
```

It did not like that

Comment: The answer to that comment seems to be

```df %>%    group_by(across(grouping)) ```